# How to create fallout intensity on a generated mesh in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, mesh, unity-shader-graph, dynamic-mesh

So I was able to generate a circle mesh in Unity to basically see the other characters when they are inside of it, and hide the characters when they are outside of it, and partially hide and show the character if they are partially in or outside of it. Below is an image of what I was able to generate, but the thing is, the edges are very sharp and I would like to have some **Fallout Intensity** on the mesh. Just like with Lights in Unity, where they have a fallout intensity at the edge of the lights.

**Image of Generated Mesh**
[image]

As you can see, the edges of the mesh are very sharp and thats not the kind of effect am after, I would like to add some fallout to that, and adjust it.

**Here is The Code That Generates The Mesh**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class FieldOfView : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fieldOfView = 360f;
    public int numberEdges = 360;
    public float initalAngle = 0;
    public float visionDistance = 8f;
    public LayerMask layerMask;

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3 origin;

    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        origin = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        GenerateUpdateMesh();
    }

    private void GenerateUpdateMesh()
    {
        float actualAngle = initalAngle;
        float incrementAngle = fieldOfView / numberEdges;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[numberEdges + 1];
        int[] triangles = new int[numberEdges * 3];

        vertices[0] = origin;

        int verticeIndex = 1;
        int triangleIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberEdges; i++)
        {
            Vector3 actualVertices;
            RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, GetVectorFromAngle(actualAngle), visionDistance, layerMask);
            if (raycastHit2D.collider == null)
            {
                // No hit
                actualVertices = origin + GetVectorFromAngle(actualAngle) * visionDistance;
            }
            else
            {
                // Hit object
                actualVertices = raycastHit2D.point;
            }

            vertices[verticeIndex] = actualVertices;

            if (i > 0)
            {
                triangles[triangleIndex + 0] = 0;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 1] = verticeIndex - 1;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 2] = verticeIndex;

                triangleIndex += 3;
            }

            verticeIndex++;
            actualAngle -= incrementAngle;
        }

        // We form the last triangle
        triangles[triangleIndex + 0] = 0;
        triangles[triangleIndex + 1] = verticeIndex - 1;
        triangles[triangleIndex + 2] = 1;


        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    Vector3 GetVectorFromAngle(float angle)
    {
        float angleRad = angle * (Mathf.PI / 180f);
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angleRad), Mathf.Sin(angleRad));
    }

    public void SetOrigin(Vector3 newOrigin)
    {
        origin = newOrigin;
    }
}
```

What do I do here to add some **Fallout Intensity**? All the help is really appreciated. And Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is really a mesh problem, it looks like you are doing everything correctly here. What I think you want to do is either make a custom shader that does alpha blending around edges (you could also generate an image texture/occlusion map and feed that in) or you could try making a "custom pass" that can fade out the edges of your fog of war meshes.

Comment: That's what I been trying to do, I been trying to create some sort of fading out with shader. But I do not know anything about shader or shader graph. All I was trying to do was just add a fersnal effect and pass that through the alpha channel . So how do I go about creating an alpha blending?

Comment: Good question. Fresnel would be perfect if your mesh wasn't essentially a flat plane. Custom Passes are probably overkill so lets ignore that for now. If I were trying this. I would probably use the UV channel (looks like you are leaving that blank in your mesh) to  store blending values. It seems like you probably know which edges are the outside of the mesh (due to your raycasting) so you could probably set your uvs to 0,0 (transparent) here and set your inside vertex uvs to 1,1 (opaque). Then your shader can just grab the value from the current UV and set it to alpha.

Comment: I also just found this with google, looks like a similar approach for feathering the edges of shapes: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/main/Assets/Shaders/FeatheredPlaneShader.shader